# Collection view cell background colours reverse on reloadData() Swift/Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uicollectionview

**NOTE -** This question was edited significantly on 22/08/2020. Any answers or comments before this edit may not (or may still) make sense. As the question (and possibly the existing answers) may be valid, I don't believe deleting the question is of benefit to others.

=======================================

**SWIFT 5**

---

***The Problem***

I have a collection view, which is filled with data from Firebase. As part of this data, a "colour" is passed for each item. This colour is an int, which the cell looks up in a table and draws.

[image]

A fragment of the code used to assign the colour:

```
let purpleGrad = [#colorLiteral(red: 0.4392156863, green: 0.4193316882, blue: 1, alpha: 1),#colorLiteral(red: 0.4392156863, green: 0.4193316882, blue: 1, alpha: 1)]
let blueGrad = [#colorLiteral(red: 0.2392156869, green: 0.6745098233, blue: 0.9686274529, alpha: 1),#colorLiteral(red: 0.2392156869, green: 0.6745098233, blue: 0.9686274529, alpha: 1)]
let pinkGrad = [#colorLiteral(red: 0.9098039269, green: 0.4784313738, blue: 0.6431372762, alpha: 1),#colorLiteral(red: 0.9098039269, green: 0.4784313738, blue: 0.6431372762, alpha: 1)]
let yellowGrad = [#colorLiteral(red: 0.7254902124, green: 0.4784313738, blue: 0.09803921729, alpha: 1),#colorLiteral(red: 0.7254902124, green: 0.4784313738, blue: 0.09803921729, alpha: 1)]
        
let colorsTable2: [Int: [UIColor]] = [0: purpleGrad, 1: blueGrad, 2: pinkGrad, 3: yellowGrad, 4: greenBlue]
```

When the collection view first draws, the colours show in the correct order. When the prices update from Apple (when `reloadData()` is called), the collection view then draws backwards.

In the following picture, the left side is how the collection view loads before the prices (which is correct, and always loads with the correct colours). The right side is after the prices have loaded (which is a reversal of the left side, and always loads this exact way).

[image]

---

***Possible Solutions***

Previous comments suggested dictionaries may be the cause of this error - whilst this may still be the case, I do not believe this is the issue. The ordering is always correct, and the colours ALWAYS reverse exactly, rather than just redrawing with random colours.

I am unsure as to what else to try - to my knowledge, reloadData() is required to update the collection view when the price is pulled.

Comment: I understand the question but there's far too much code to be useful. Please review  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also, there are a number of references to FirebaseManager. What does this `dataSet = FirebaseManager.shared.courses` do for example? Does it return data from a dataSource or does it query Firebase in some way?

Comment: Thanks for your input Jay. I have edited the code to include what I believe are only the necessary parts. FirebaseManager.shared.courses is what the Firebase query returns (as an NSDictionary), allowing me to access it outside FirebaseManager.

Comment: A Firebase query does not return an NSDictionary. It returns a [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DataSnapshot) which is ordered. *Your code* is casting it to an NSDictionary `let downloadedCourses = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary` which then makes the returned data unordered. That's not a good idea if you count on the ordering. See the EDIT to my answer.

Comment: Also note this comment in your code **Divide the difference by the total number of cells** during the color calculation. That would indicate the cell colors will vary depending on how many cells there are? Also, it's unclear why calculations are used to color cells. Why don't you just save the cell color with the data in Firebase - then you can remove all of that code and the cell will always be the correct color regardless of what order it's in (since you are using un-ordered data from Firebase per my above comment and answer)

Comment: The calculations are to do with a gradient across the cells. The idea was to specify a base colour in firebase (e.g. 1) which correlates to a colour gradient in Swift. When drawing the collection view, Swift can calculate the number of cells so that the gradient across the cells (from top to bottom) will be even.

Comment: Understood. Your calculation could be causing a color shift issue but again, using NSDictionary throws all ordering to the wind and it really seems to be the cause of the problem.

Comment: The question just isn't answerable. You're loading data from Firebase into a var that's not used anywhere else in the code in your question `self.courses = downloadedCourses!`. Your collectionView dataSource is an unordered dictionary `cell.dataSet = currentDataSet()` and somewhere in your code you're calling `setGradientBackground` but we don't know from where. It's also unclear what or when the data is actually loaded from Firebase - from within a cell? We really need clarification of both the code and the question.

Comment: Jay - let me rewrite the question. Should I delete this post and create a new question, or edit the current question?

Comment: I would probably recommend deleting it since there's a lot of code and a lot of missing pieces - it would probably be a re-write anyway. When you post a new question, keep the question clear and on topic, minimal code to reproduce the issue and eliminate those dictionaries as they are not being used correctly for this use case.

Comment: @Jay, question rewritten and edited on this post as I still think the other answers may be valuable to others. Hopefully the updated question makes it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when tableview cells get messy by refreshing or scrolling, it is because there is no default value for data which is changing in each cell. So you might want to consider a primary value for color Int (like 0) and set cell's background color to nil, before fetching and setting actual values.

Comment: Just to clarify ... the problem does not occur on scroll. The cells do not "flicker", so I don't think it is anything to do the with the background colour. It is the fact that the collection view redraws itself backwards when the prices are updated from Apple.

Answer (score 0):

This is a wild guess because there's too much code but you're using a lot of NSDictionaries (please use Swift Dictionary).

Dictionaries are unordered pairs so you cannot rely on the order of the data when iterating over it. So for example here:

```
let course = course as? NSDictionary
for (courseID, courseData) in course! {
   let courseData = courseData as? NSDictionary ?? NSDictionary()
   let subjects = courseData["subjects"] ?? NSDictionary()
```

That's going to iterate over the data in course potentially different each time it's run (the child data is unordered).

So you probably have some disconnect between the ordering of the data and getting the associated background color.

**EDIT**

The data returned from Firebase is being cast to a Dictionary by your code, that will then loose the ordering.

```
let downloadedCourses = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
```

If you want to maintain the ordering and use the child data as snapshots (recommended) do this

```
let orderedCourses = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
```

Comment: The colour is always a complete reversal though no matter how many times it is tested, rather than just a random order like I would expect from a Dictionary.

Comment: @lcolli98 I am not seeing the colors 'reversed' in the question, they are just in different order - it looks random, which is exactly what you'd see from a dictionary.

Comment: I will try what you have suggested Jay and see if it works, however the colours are reversing. In the first screenshot (before the prices load), the colours are indigo, pink, yellow, purple, purple, which is what it should be. In the second screenshot (after the prices load), the colours are purple, purple, yellow, pink, indigo. This always occurs and is always the complete opposite of the starting colours.

Comment: @lcolli98 I am looking at the screen shot in your question and 'courses' is red, and then below that 'courses' is still red. Becoming a pilot is purple, and then below that, it's still purple, although a slightly different purple. So it doesn't looked reversed to me.

Comment: Jay, sorry, I'm not explaining this clearly enough. The "Courses" title is on the navigation bar, which should stay red. If you look at the colours of the cells themselves, it is a mirror image.

First screenie: Becoming a pilot is indigo, PPL(A) is pink, then yellow, purple, dark purple.
Second screenie: Becoming a pilot is dark purple, PPL(A) is purple, then yellow, pink, indigo.

The order of the colouring reverses every time in the same way.